# How to repeat data with flow_from_directory in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, data-generation

I am trying to use **`keras`** ***flow_from_directory*** to train a model. But it does not repeat
data after the epoch(i.e. when all the data has been iterated). I could not find any 
option to do so either. Below is my code for data generation while training.
For example if total images = 70
               batch_size   = 32
then in 1st and 2nd iteration is gives 32 images, but in third it gives 6 images.

```
# data generation from directory without labels  
trn = datagen.flow_from_directory(os.path.join(BASE, 'train_gen'),
                                         batch_size=batch_size,
                                         target_size=(inp_shape[:2]),
                                         class_mode=None)
X = trn.next() # getting a batch of data.
```

I want the data generator to start repeating data after it's exhausted.

Actually I am trying to train a GAN, where a batch images are generated from Generator-Model and then it is concatenated with a batch of real images and then passed to Discriminator-Model and GAN-Model to train. I can't figure out how can I use ***fit_generator*** in this, Code is as below:

```
def train(self, inp_shape, batch_size=1, n_epochs=1000):
    BASE = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Dataset/GAN'

    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    trn_dist = datagen.flow_from_directory(os.path.join(BASE, 'train_gen'),
                                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                                      target_size=(inp_shape[:2]),
                                                      seed = 1360000,
                                                      class_mode=None)

    val_dist = datagen.flow_from_directory(os.path.join(BASE, 'test_gen'),
                                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                                      target_size=(inp_shape[:2]),
                                                      class_mode=None)

    trn_real = datagen.flow_from_directory(os.path.join(BASE, 'train_real'),
                                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                                      target_size=(inp_shape[:2]),
                                                      seed = 1360000,
                                                      class_mode=None)

    for e in range(n_epochs):

      real_images = trn_real.next()

      dist_images = trn_dist.next()

      gen_images = self.generator.predict(dist_images)

      factor = inp_shape[0]/250
      gen_res = ndi.zoom(gen_images, (1, factor, factor, 1), order=2)      

      X = np.concatenate([real_images, gen_res])

      y = np.zeros(2*batch_size)
      y[:batch_size] = 1.

      self.discriminator.trainable = True
      self.discriminator.fit(X, y, batch, n_epochs)

      self.discriminator.trainable = False

      self.model.fit(gen_res, y[:batch_size])
      print ('> training --- epoch=%d/%d' % (e, n_epochs))
      if e > 0 and e % 2000 == 0:
        self.model.save('%s/models/gan_model_%d_.h5'%(BASE, e))
```

PS: I am new to Gans please correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

To shed some light on the problem, First, you need to know the parameters of `flow_from_directory`. `batch_size` determines the number of samples to be loaded for computation and the `epoch` determines the number of times that you what Keras to pass through all your data. In essence, if you set your `epoch=2` and `batch_size=32` it means that Keras will go through all your data twice with splitting your data in `mini-batches` with 32 samples of your data. then what's missing in your code is essentially the epoch parameter.
I recommend setting the steps_per_epoch and validation_data as well. the `steps_per_epoch` determined the number of batches in each epoch than to visit all your samples in each epoch set the `steps_per_epoch` as follows.

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples/train_generator.batch_size, epochs=10, validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=validation_generator.samples/validation_generator.batch_size)
```

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, I am trying to train a GAN, where a batch of image has to be passed to the model. So I am using a loop for n_epochs, rather than using fit_generator. Please find the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

The `flow_from_directory` method is made to be used with the `fit_generator` function. The `fit_generator` function allows you to specify the number of epochs.

```
model.fit_generator(trn, epochs=epochs)
```

Where `model` refers to the model object you want to train. Should solve your problem. These functions are well explained in the Keras documentation

Comment: I am trying to train a GAN, where inputs from two sources are concatenated and resized and then passed to a model, So I can work with only batch at a time. So there is no way to set repeat mode in flow_from_directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can always specify `steps_per_epoch` argument in `fit_generator` method. This will enable you to repeat data when `steps_per_epoch` > total_samples // batch_size.

Answer (score 1):

I found a hack to make the 2nd generator with lesser images to "reset" its index, hence outputting batch of 32 images instead of 6 images as you mentioned earlier.

Looking at your code, I supposed `trn_real` is the generator with more images and `trn_dist` is the generator with lesser images. At each iteration, compare the batch shape, if they are not equal (meaning the generator reaches the end of the index, hence output lesser images), then reset the generator as follows:

```
real_images = trn_real.next()
dist_images = trn_dist.next()
if real_images.shape != dist_images.shape:
    trn_dist.reset() # reset the generator with lesser images
    dist_images = trn_dist.next()
```